# "Uniswap: Insufficient liquidity for this trade." when adding liquidity through contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, uniswap, testnets, liquidity-provider

I am trying to create an Uniswap v2 liquidity pool for my token with custom tax fees (0x0AeE891A17e570Eba92A9138dB45DA2ecFAd7082) on Sepolia. To create the pool and add liquidity the function `openTrading()` gets called. I have sent half of the token supply and 0.05 Sepolia ETH to the contract prior to calling the function and etherscan shows that the pool is created. https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x9b39c537687af73241ecb90fc6ee3d7f45456f4e28ea48abee73ae3b280e66a0

Whenever I try to swap my tokens for ether on Uniswap it gives the error: "Uniswap: Insufficient liquidity for this trade". What am I doing wrong here?

```
    function openTrading() external onlyOwner() {
        require(!tradingOpen,"trading is already open");
        uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008);
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), _tTotal);
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH());
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: address(this).balance}(address(this),balanceOf(address(this)),0,0,owner(),block.timestamp);
        IERC20(uniswapV2Pair).approve(address(uniswapV2Router), type(uint).max);
        swapEnabled = true;
        tradingOpen = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the error when you execute `openTrading`? or when you try to swap tokens in that pool after opening it?

If it is the second, you are probably causing a large price change because of the amount you are swapping compared with the existing liquidity. Try trading a really really small amount. If that doesn't revert, that could confirm this hypothesis. To fix it, try increasing the slippage (by modifying the minimum tokens you accept in return when you execute the uniswap swap.